# Django REST -- How to "modify" value before returning the REST response?

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework

I have done some research, but I'm not quite sure what I'm technically looking for so I didn't find much information. I am using Django REST.

**model**

```
class Car(models.Model)
    name =  name = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, db_index=True)
    speed = models.IntegerField(default=SPEED.FAST)
```

**view**

```
class CarViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Car.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CarSerializer
```

**serializer**

```
class CarSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Car
```

**Question:** My `speed` field in `Car` model is an integer, when I access the REST endpoint API, I don't want to return an integer, but instead a string. Basically:

```
if speed is 0:
    return "slow"
else:
    return "fast"
```

So an example JSON response is:

```
{ name: "ferrari", speed: "fast" }
```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You can use [`SerializerMethodField`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield):

```
class CarSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    speed = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_speed(self, obj):
        if obj.speed == 0:
            return "slow"
        else:
            return "fast"

    class Meta:
        model = Car
        fields = ('name', 'speed')
```

Comment: Is `fields = ('name', 'speed')` required? I didn't include that and it's working perfectly for me. Just wondering.

Comment: Well, not required if you want to pull all the fields. I usually work with very big models and I need just some fields. But it's not required.

Comment: [As of DRF 3.5, it is now required to use `'__all__'` if you want all fields](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/community/3.5-announcement/#modelserializer-fields-and-exclude).

Comment: One of the major issue of this approach is it makes the field ```read_only``` Is there a better way of implementing this by not making the field read_only

Answer (score 22):

Adding another approach -

```
class CarSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Car
        fields = ('name', 'speed')

    def to_representation(self, data):
        data = super(CarSerializer, self).to_representation(data)
        data['speed'] = 'slow' if data.get('speed') == 0 else 'fast'
        return data
```

Also, one improvement in @Gocht answer.
Better practice to omit extra else statement while using conditional return in method get_speed -

```
def get_speed(self, obj):
    if obj.speed == 0:
        return "slow"
    return "fast"
```

Comment: Thank you, in my case helped first variant.